# Typeorm tests using queryRunner transactions failing

Tags: typeorm

I am trying to write jest tests with typeorm (+Postgres). I would like them to run in parallel and by starting a transaction, executing the test and then reverting the transaction for each test.

The setup I use for this is:

```js
let queryRunner: QueryRunner
let em: EntityManager;

beforeAll(async () => {
  const testAppDataSource = await getTestAppDataSource()
  queryRunner = testAppDataSource.createQueryRunner()
  queryRunner.connect()
})

beforeEach(async () => {
  await queryRunner.startTransaction()
  em = queryRunner.manager
})

afterEach(async () => {
  await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction()
})

afterAll(async () => {
  await queryRunner.release()
})

test("testname", async() => {
  // perform operations with em
}
```

Where the function `getTestAppDataSource` is defined as:

```js
const testAppDataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions)

export const getTestAppDataSource = async () => {
  if (!testAppDataSource.isInitialized) {
    await testAppDataSource.initialize()
  }
  return testAppDataSource
}
```

When I run my tests sequentially with the `--runInBand` flag they work fine. When run them in parallel they fail with

```
    QueryFailedError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_type_typname_nsp_index"
```

And

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rollbackTransaction')
```

Usually there is still 1 test which succeeds.

It seems that the tests are interfering with each other. Is the `dataSource.createQueryRunner()` somehow giving the "same" queryRunner to all the tests?

---

Edit:

I also tried replacing `const testAppDataSource = await getTestAppDataSource()` with

```js
  const testAppDataSource = new DataSource(testDataSourceOptions)
  await testAppDataSource.initialize()
```

But to no avail